# How to know float or integer?

Tags: c++

there are `2`, `2.0` or `2.55`. How to know float or integer in C++.

I use `ceil`, `floor` and `typeid` functions, it always give me incorrect output

How can I do?

Code:

```
struct CalExp {
  char id[500];
};

double Operator( CalExp* op, int i, double num1, double num2 ) {
    if (strcmp(op[i].id, "*") == 0) return num1 * num2;
    else if (strcmp(op[i].id, "/") == 0) return num1 / num2;
    else if (strcmp(op[i].id, "+") == 0) return num1 + num2;
    else if (strcmp(op[i].id, "-") == 0) return num1 - num2;
    return 0.0;
} // Operator()

void Calculation( vector<Token> token ) { // math
    CalExp postfix[500] = { '\0' }; // Like 2 3 +
    ...
    int top = 0;
    float cal_array[200] = { 0.0 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < postfix_len; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(postfix[i].id, "+") == 0 ) || (strcmp(postfix[i].id, "-") == 0) ||
            (strcmp(postfix[i].id, "*") == 0 ) || (strcmp(postfix[i].id, "/") == 0)) {
            if (cal_array[top] == 0.0 && strcmp(postfix[i].id, "/") == 0) { // eg. 2/0
                cout << "ERROR";
                return;
            } // if
            cal_array[top - 1] = Operator( postfix, i, cal_array[top-1], cal_array[top]);
            top--;
        } // if
        
        else {
            cal_array[++top] = atof(postfix[i].id); 
        } // else
    } // for

  if ( /*has "." */ ) cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << cal_array[top];
  else cout << (int)cal_array[top];
```

Comment: Where are you getting `2` and `2.0`? As literals in source code? As text input from a stream? Can you give an example of what you tried and what "not correct" meant in practice?

Comment: Integers do not have decimal points. Floats do. Without more information, that is the best description of the difference. You've provided no details or context. You may want to review [ask] for some suggestions.

Comment: @NathanPierson I rewrite it.

Comment: `cal_array` is an array of `float`s. So `cal_array[top]` is always a `float`, and never an `int`. So I don't understand how you think you could tell the difference between `4.0` and `4`. If you wanted to treat `4.25` one way and `4.0` another way, that would be one thing. But there's no detectible difference between "a `float` whose value is `4.0`" and "a `float` whose value is `4`"

Comment: @NathanPierson Because when I input 2+3, the output is 5. However I input 2.0+3, the output is 5.0. I wonder if it can auto recognize whether it is an ```integer``` or a ```floating```

Comment: Give an example of what you mean by this. For myself, even if I do `std::cout << (2.0 + 3);`, I get an output of `5`, not `5.0`. But also now you're talking about more code that you aren't showing that's different from what you have in important ways, because in the code you've posted everything gets assigned to a `float` and in the code in your comment... I don't know what happens to `2.0+3`.

Comment: `2 + 3` is an `int`. `2.0 + 3` is a `double`. But if you write `float five = 2 + 3;`, `five` is still a `float`, and not an `int` or a `double`. Storing the result of a computation in a variable can result in conversions taking place.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thank you for your patience. I upload my code. Hope this solves the problem

Comment: This is the same issue I pointed out when you just had the description of `cal_array`. `cal_array` stores `float`s. `Operator` returns a `double`. `atof` returns a `double`. If you want to handle `"2.0 3 +"` differently than `"2 3 +"`, you need to figure out a way to handle the computations that doesn't immediately store every numerical value in a floating-point type, because once you do there is no longer a difference between `2.0` and `2`.

Comment: Things similar to `2.0 + 3 = 5.0` happen because of [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

Answer (score 1):

Since these are types in the system, you can use type traits:

```
auto v = 2;
std::cout << std::is_integral_v<decltype(v)> << "\n"; // true
std::cout << std::is_floating_point_v<decltype(v)> << "\n"; // false
```

If you want to check against a specific type, you can use `is_same`:

```
std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(v), int> << "\n"; // true
std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(v), std::uint8_t> << "\n"; // false
```